# Rails 6.0 ActiveStorage direct upload : wrong Request URL in prod but not in dev

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, rails-activestorage

In production I get an error 404 for direct_upload in my back office /admin

I have followed step by step the rails tutorials

I have put direct_uploads in javascript/utils

in application.js I have add :

```
import * as ActiveStorage from "activestorage";
import "../utils/direct_uploads.js"
```

add prefix in production.rb :
`config.active_storage.routes_prefix = '/img'`

When I want ti upload a picture I get an error 404 :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () => /img/direct_uploads

and

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://example.com/img/direct_uploads' from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

My cors config in S3 :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>https://*.example.com</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

**Edit :** .

I added the gem 'rack-cors' and get now, an error 422

```
XHR finished loading: OPTIONS "https://example.com/img/direct_uploads"  

"https://example.com/img/direct_uploads".  

XHR failed loading: POST "https://example.com/img/direct_uploads".
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Having this issue as well.